# Bower: Install 2 versions of jQuery

Tags: terminal, bower, multiple-versions

How would I go about installing 2 versions of jQuery **using bower**? I want to have v2.0  as well as 1.9.1 for browser support fallback

The issue I'm having is that if you run  `bower install jquery#1.9.1 jquery#2.0.0` the first version gets overwritten by the second because they are the same component

Comment: Hope this can help you,http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: @dreamweiver i dont need two versions running at the same time, I want to install two seperate versions using bower

Comment: editing tags, since this isn't really a jQuery question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the dependencies part of your bower.json you can have something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.0.0",
    "jquery-1.9.1": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
}
```

One shouldn't normally have to do this, but sometimes you have to maintain / migrate an existing website that (for whatever reason) uses different versions of jquery in different pages!

Comment: what about: `"jquery-1.9.1": "jquery#1.9.1"`

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.0.0",
    "jquery-1.9.1": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
}


----------
This answer is working fine.But when I minify and uglify the code only one version is available and so the code which use other version is getting broken.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 158):

According to the [bower docs](https://github.com/bower/bower#installing-packages-and-dependencies)

> Bower offers several ways to install packages:
>
> ```
> # Using the dependencies listed in the current directory's bower.json
> bower install
> # Using a local or remote package
> bower install <package>
> # Using a specific version of a package
> bower install <package>#<version>
> # Using a different name and a specific version of a package
> bower install <name>=<package>#<version>
> ```

You can install two different versions of jQuery like so:

```
bower install jquery-legacy=jquery#1.10 jquery-modern=jquery#2
```

Or, if you prefer to set that up in a `bower.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery-legacy": "jquery#1.10",
    "jquery-modern": "jquery#2"
}
```

Comment: thanks! good to know, is that a newly added feature? I dont think this was a possibility when I was originally seeking an answer

Comment: @AdamCoulombe looks like this was added as of v1.0.0. It's been stable for a relatively long period of time (software wise) but wasn't in any pre-release of bower.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer

Comment: Definitely this should be the answer

Comment: This really helps. Follow up question: how do you specify which jQuery version needs to be used on another library? I have an open question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006850/how-to-customize-javascript-libraries-and-still-use-bower).

Answer (score 12):

From the command line, if you just want the latest 1.x and 2.x versions, you can loosen the constraints in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18241613/424245).

So:

`bower install jquery-legacy=jquery#1.10 jquery-modern=jquery#2`

would become:

`bower install jquery-legacy=jquery#^1 jquery-modern=jquery`

Comment: As the PHP/Packagist community is now learning, `bower install jquery-legacy=jquery#^1 jquery-modern=jquery` -- while looser-- still doesn't place an upper bound on the "modern" version. A better loose constraint would be: `bower install jquery-legacy=jquery#^1 jquery-modern=jquery#^2`, since it keeps the modern with an upper bound to prevent major breaking changes. By the time 2.x isn't "modern" anymore, i'd assume you would change the package name anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## bower.json:

This is how i did it...

"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "2.0.0",
    "**jquery-old**": "1.9.1"
    ...
}

Second version, can be any version, old or new. You just have to add a different key. Like **jquery-old**

## Install

bower install --save **jquery-old**

### Use

Now you can use either one of the jquery version:

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/bower/directory/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/bower/directory/**jquery-old**/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

### Bonus

"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "2.0.0",
    "**jquery-old**": "1.9.1"
    "**jquery-latest**": "^3.3.1"
    ...
}