# Two versions of same npm package in Node application

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm working on a CLI tool in NodeJS that uses another NodeJs package that we develop, which is an SDK.

The thing is, we just published a V2 version of that SDK, and we want to offer the CLI user a legacy mode, so they can use either the first or second version of our SDK, like so:

```
$ cli do-stuff
#execute sdk v2
```

Or

```
$ LEGACY_MODE='on' cli do-stuff
#execute sdk v1
```

My problem is that I did not found any clean way to use two versions of the same dependency in my CLI.
I tried to use [npm-install-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-version) package. It works well on my local environment, but after publishing my cli and doing `npm install -g my-cli`, it doesn't work anymore, because it creates a node_modules folder in the current folder, instead of the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-cli` folder.
I also tried [multidep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multidep), and I have kind of the same issue.

For now, my package.json do not contain at all my sdk, but I would like to have something like :

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-sdk": "2.0.0"
  "my-sdk-legacy": "1.0.0"
}
```

Or

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-sdk": ["2.0.0", "1.0.0"]
}
```

I haven't found anything else yet. I'm thinking about publishing the first version of my sdk package with another name, like "my-sdk-legacy", but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Any solution for that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install multiple versions of package using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So this is actually a quite common scenario which was addressed several times.

There is a closed issue for [npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499) and open issue for [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1508) package managers.

---

The first solution was suggested by the author of NPM in [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499#issuecomment-71089080) GH comment:

Publish a separate package under a different name. It will require a specific version inside.

```
{ "name": "express3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description":"Express version 3",
  "dependencies": { "express":"3" } }

// index.js
module.exports = require('express')
```

In your case you'll publish `my-sdk-v1` and `my-sdk-v2`. And from now you can easily install 2 versions of a package in one project without running into conflicts.

```
const mySDKLegacy = require('my-sdk-v1');
const mySDKModern = require('my-sdk-v2');
```

The [second way](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499#issuecomment-129481232) pretty much the same idea proposed - use git url:

```
{
    "my-sdk-v1": "git://github.com/user/my-sdk#1.0.0",
    "my-sdk-v2": "git://github.com/user/my-sdk#2.0.0"
}
```

Unlike npm package, you are free to choose any name you wish! The source of truth is the git url.

[Later](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499#issuecomment-230673987) `npm-install-version` popped up. Buuut, as you already proved, its usage is a bit limited. Since it spawns a child process to execute some commands and writes to tmp dirs. Not the most reliable way for a CLI.

To sum up: you're left with choices 1 & 2. I'd stick with the first one, since the github repo name & tags could change.

2nd option with git url is better when you want to change a version to depend more frequently. Imagine you want to publish a security patch for my-sdk-v1 legacy. Will be easier to reference a git url then publish `my-sdk-v1.1` to npm again and again.

Comment: I tried the second version, but the thing is, npm do not rename the folder after the checkout from git.
In the ```node_modules``` folder, there is only one folder named "my-sdk". So the following code doesn't work either
```require('my-sdk-v1');```
But I can do ```require('my-sdk');```
So I think I'll stick to the first version, even if it's a bit less convenient to me.
Thanks

Comment: For our version, we had to change the destination package's name as well.

Comment: By the way, one thing not exactly mentioned, is that a simple fork of the project with the package name changed should suffice.  No need to publish it.

Comment: I tried the second option to have two version of bootstrap. And I get the following error:  Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "Invalid tar header. Maybe the tar is corrupted or it needs to be gunzipped?"

Answer (score 130):

*Based on [my answer for a similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495651/7770056)*

As of [npm v6.9.0,](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.9.0) npm now supports package aliases. It [implements the same syntax](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0001-package-aliases.md#detailed-explanation) as Yarn uses:

```
npm install my-sdk-legacy@npm:my-sdk@1
npm install my-sdk
```

This adds the following to `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-sdk-legacy": "npm:my-sdk@^1.0.0",
  "my-sdk": "2.0.0"
}
```

This seems to me the most elegant solution available, and is compatible with the [Yarn solution proposed by @Aivus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770328/two-versions-of-same-npm-package-in-node-application/52311693#52311693)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with `@types/[...]` packages.

Comment: @RoyTinker you mean scoped packages? It should work with the following syntax: `npm install react-types@npm:@types/react` (for the React TS definitions installed under the alias `react-types`)

Comment: @RensBaardman Thanks. Looks like I was in the wrong directory - please disregard my comment. It works now.

Comment: What if the package is to be used as npx? Namely a cli package that uses a command such as "typedoc"? How to use both the commands?

Comment: This should be the approved answer

Answer (score 15):

So to just add up to current solutions you can also provide packages like so:

```
yarn add my-sdk-newest@npm:my-sdk
```

or in `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "my-sdk-newest": "npm:my-sdk",
  "my-sdk": "1.0.0"
  ...
}
```

if you only care about specific legacy version and the newest.

Answer (score 6):

Do `npm i alias@npm:package_name@package_version`

Inside package.json use `“alias”: “npm:package_name@package_version”`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run two versions of [tfjs-core](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core) and found that both needed to be built after being installed.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "tfjs-core-0.14.3": "git://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core#bb0a830b3bda1461327f083ceb3f889117209db2",
  "tfjs-core-1.1.0": "git://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core#220660ed8b9a252f9d0847a4f4e3c76ba5188669"
}
```

Then:

```
cd node_modules/tfjs-core-0.14.3 && yarn install && yarn build-npm && cd ../../
cd node_modules/tfjs-core-1.1.0  && yarn install && yarn build-npm && cd ../../
```

And finally, to use the libraries:

```
import * as tf0143 from '../node_modules/tfjs-core-0.14.3/dist/tf-core.min.js';
import * as tf110  from '../node_modules/tfjs-core-1.1.0/dist/tf-core.min.js';
```