# To have two version bootstrap in same package.json

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4

I have a package.json and I need to have two version boostrap in same project.

How can to do it ?

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  }
```

I have the version bootstrap 3, and I need to have the version 4 also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two versions of same npm package in Node application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770328/two-versions-of-same-npm-package-in-node-application)

Comment: Yes I saw that question, but how can I include two version of bootstrap ? What url I must to include

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install multiple versions of package using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm)