# How do I mention which version of a package to be installed for a dependency that the main project uses - Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, node-modules, package.json

I'm using `dependency1` and `dependency2` in my project. `dependency2` also needs to install `dependency1` inside it. I need the latest version of `dependency1` in my project but `dependency2` needs a specific older version of `dependency1`. Is there a way to ensure the packages are installed with different versions? Can I do this within my `package.json` file?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770328/two-versions-of-same-npm-package-in-node-application It uses aliases in the package.json dependency section. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm/56495651#56495651 and here https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package-in-npm-71c29b12e253

Comment: @besjon_c I just found out I'm supposed to use overrides. Will add an answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with `overrides` in my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "dependency1" : "v@latest",
    "dependency2" : "v@latest"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "dependency2": {
      "dependency1": "v@older"
    }
  }
```