# Yarn installing multiple versions of the same package

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have `angular` in my dependencies at 1.5.11:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.11",
        "angular-foundation": "0.7.0"
    }
}
```

`angular-foundation` happens to depend on `angular@>=1.3.0`.

Why does Yarn install `angular@1.6.9` as a nested dependency of angular-foundation instead of using the project's version? This causes angular to exist twice in the app and doesn't work properly:

`node_modules
  angular (1.5.11)
  angular-foundation (0.7.0)
    node_modules
      angular (1.6.9)`

This doesn't happen with npm@5.6.0 - npm uses 1.5.11 for both the app and the package.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use `Yarn` resolutions for this

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

So your `package.json` will become like this

```
{
  "name": "depdencies",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",

    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.11",
        "angular-foundation": "0.7.0"
    },
    "resolutions": {
      "**/angular": "1.5.11"
    }
}
```

Which tells `yarn` that any child angular dependency will be set to `1.5.11`. After updating this run below

```
$ rm yarn.lock
$ yarn
```

Comment: Deleting the yarn.lock is generally not advised, especially on big/"old" projects. The documentation you link advises to only run `yarn install` afterwards

Answer (score 21):

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add/#toc-yarn-add-alias

`yarn add <alias-package>@npm:<package>`

`yarn add react17@npm:react@17`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: the explanation is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm