# How to install with npm 2 different bootstrap version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, package, installation

I would like to use bootstrap 3.3.7 and 4.0.0 in same project. I tried to use the following in my package.json but it's not working:

```
"dependencies": {
 "bootstrap": "^3.3.7, ^4.0.0"
}
```

I tried the following too and that's not working too:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "bootstrap-4.0.0": "bootstrap#4.0.0"
}
```

How can i install that different version of node package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install multiple versions of package using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm)

Comment: Sorry but I still didn't find the commands for npm multiple bootstrap install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed the different versions via [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm), you can use them like that:

`npm i bootstrap-3@npm:bootstrap-sass@\^3 bootstrap-4@npm:bootstrap@\^4 bootstrap-5@npm:bootstrap@\^5 bootstrap`

And then like [Talita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2863666/talita) says, you can use aliases.

package.json:

```
(...)
  "dependencies": {    
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "bootstrap-3": "npm:bootstrap-sass@^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-4": "npm:bootstrap@^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-5": "npm:bootstrap@^5.0.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use aliases like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap3": "npm:bootstrap@3.3.7"
}
```

Comment: Not working:17 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for bootstrap3@npm:bootstrap@3.3.7 Invalid dependency type requested: alias