# npm install from private repository as a different package name

Tags: javascript, git, npm

I need to install a module from a private github repo. In order to do that I'll run `npm install git+https://[API-KEY]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<name>/<repo>.git#<branch>`. 
My `package.json` file would look something like this:

```
"dependencies: {
    ...
    "private-repo-name": "git+https://[API-KEY]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<name>/<repo>.git#<branch>",
    ...
}
```

In this case, `"private-repo-name"` corresponds to the `name` field of the `package.json` of the private repo, i.e.:

```
"name": "private-repo-name"
```

My question is: How do I change the package name during `npm install` without changing the `name` field of the private repo?

Note: For public npm modules this wouldn't be a problem due to npm modules not sharing namespaces in the npm registry, but for privately developed modules that arent hosted in npm, there is a potential for the module name to conflict with current or future public npm modules in the npm registry.

Comment: I haven't researched this (so offering as a comment, not an answer), but I would imagine if you scope the private package in its `package.json` you would be fine. By setting `name` in `private-repo-name`'s `package.json` then npm will install it with that name. Might I suggest something along the lines of `@my-company/private-package-name` for the name.

Comment: In this case, assume that I cannot change anything from the private repo. Thus I can't change the `name` field in `private-repo-name`'s `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by setting up system `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable to your private repo. after that it will work for command like `npm install`. but it will install the package with the name they have in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can simply run `npm install new-name@git+https://[API-KEY]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<name>/<repo>.git#<branch>`

[how to install multiple versions of package using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm)

There's no coupling between the keys in the `dependencies` field & the `name` field in the private repo.

i.e.

```
"dependencies: {
    ...
    "new-name": "git+https://[API-KEY]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<name>/<repo>.git#<branch>",
    ...
}
```

After this, commands like `npm update new-name` would work as expected.