# Is it possible to use different version of the same libraries in my react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, formik

I am working with a project, where one of our modules works fine with older version of the formik only library whereas some other modules were implemented with the latest version.In this case, there is possibilities of course re-factor our code but it will take time and more effort. Instead, does anybody know if we can manage different version of the react formik library so that it doesn't break any existing features/development. Any kinds of suggestions would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install multiple versions of package using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do it. If you use `npm`:

```
npm install react-table-latest@npm:react-table
npm install react-table-stable@npm:react-table@6.10.3
```

This adds the following to `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
   "react-table-latest": "npm:react-table",
   "react-table-stable": "npm:react-table@6.10.3",
}
```

And if you use `yarn` it the same. You can read about `yarn` alias [here](https://dev.to/abdelrahmanahmed/package-alias-name-using-npm-yarn-d9p)