# In React 16 project, how to use component library created by React 18

Tags: reactjs, vite, mobx, mobx-react

I'm making React UI library which uses React v18.2 and MobX v6.12. The library has React and MobX packages internally. (packed together)
I want to use the library in my another project which uses React v16.6 and MobX v4.5.

```
// my project (React v16)
function App() {
  return (
    <MyLibraryReact18 />
  );
}
```

Then these two error occurs.

First one:

> ```
> index.js:439 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called
> inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one
> of the following reasons:
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
> and fix this problem.
> ```

Second one:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
> at Object.useRef (index.js:1377:1)
> at useObserver (index.js:36726:1)
> at App (index.js:36807:1)
> at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:13644:1)
> at updateSimpleMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:13602:1)
> ```

I know the first one is just a warning. But the problem is the second one.

It seems to be due to a React version conflict, because if I downgrade the library to React 16 (no hooks), it works fine. (But I can't apply the downgrade, I have to use React 18).

How can I fix this? Is it possible to use React 18 with 16?

Comment: If there is a solution about that, I'd like to keep two versions because of migration issue. I want to check if there is a solution.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416632/is-it-possible-to-use-different-version-of-the-same-libraries-in-my-react-projec

Comment: I think you should read up on peer dependencies / externals. Might help

Comment: @TusharShahi Could you explain more? The library has React 18, MobX 6 packages internally(bundled together) so I think peer dependency, externals are not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it renders React v18 Component using React v16.
Which means:

```
// my project (React v16)
import MyLibraryReact18 from "library";

function App() {
  return (
    <MyLibraryReact18 />
  );
}
```

above code will be transpiled to:

```
// my project (React v16)
import MyLibraryReact18 from "library";

function App() {
  return React.createElement(...); // equivalent to <MyLibraryReact18 />
}
```

In this situation `React.createElement` is a React v16's method. Because the transpilation is executed in `my project` (React v16).

So the React v18 library component cannot work and the error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

I've solved this problem by making an api(e.g. `renderLibrary`) to render:

```js
// my project (React v16)
import {renderLibrary} from "library";

function timeToRender() { // call this when you need
  renderLibrary("root"); // will render MyLibraryReact18 on #root
}

function App() {
  return <div id="root" />
}
```

That api is super simple:

```js
// library

export const renderLibrary = id => {
  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.elementById(id)).render(<MyLibraryReact18 />);
};
```