# How to use 2 version of npm package in a React Native App?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

In my React Native App, I'm using the React Native Track Player package with version: `"react-native-track-player": "1.1.4". This version has a bug on iOS which mentioned in this link: [App freezes when buffering a new track](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues/548)

I've upgraded to higher version, but unfortunately, they are not compatible with my `"react-native-video": "^4.4.5"`, I can not build app on Android, just the `track-player: 1.1.4` work with it.

So I think I need to implement something like 2 version of "react-native-track-player", on Android is: "1.1.4" and iOS is "1.1.8". Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: Is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm) help?

Comment: I'm trying, iOS work as expect, but on Android it add 2 version 1.1.4 and 1.1.8 then show an error that "MusicManager$1 is defined multiple times". How can I prevent build 1.1.8 on Android ?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you could find out in build.grandle where `implementation` may implement two times, and mark up one of it and rebuild?