# Using different node modules versions from the same package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Any tricks to install multiple versions of the same node package

> npm install package@1.0.0

> npm install package@2.0.0

and later access them by different imports

```
import package1 from "package@1:0:0"
import package2 from "package@2:0:0"
```

Comment: @KiraLT , Yes it answer my question - many thanks

Comment: You can use aliases for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495651/2097494

Answer (score 0):

No. It will simply update the version that you're already have.