# How to resolve the transitive dependencies of different versions in npm?

Tags: npm, node-modules

My application depends on npm packages `ajv-keywords` & `@apideck/better-ajv-errors` which in turn are dependent on package `ajv` but of different versions as shown in below errors.

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.9.1, required by ajv-keywords@3.5.2
```

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@>=8, required by @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.2.5
```

Solutions I tried with no effect -

- Installed and executed `npm-install-peers`
- Solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495651/16958085

Below graph shows how the two packages are loaded -

```
> npm ls @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.2.5
`-- my-app@0.1.8
  `-- react-scripts@5.0.0-next.37
    `-- workbox-webpack-plugin@6.2.4
      `-- workbox-build@6.2.4
        `-- @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.2.5

> npm ls ajv-keywords@3.5.2
+-- babel-loader@8.2.2
| `-- schema-utils@2.7.1
|   `-- ajv-keywords@3.5.2
+-- my-app@0.1.8
| `-- react-scripts@5.0.0-next.37
|   `-- react-dev-utils@12.0.0-next.37
|     `-- fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.0.5
|       `-- schema-utils@2.7.0
|         `-- ajv-keywords@3.5.2  deduped
`-- webpack@5.53.0
  `-- schema-utils@3.1.1
    `-- ajv-keywords@3.5.2  deduped
```

Please suggest an appropriate solution to satisfy both the dependencies.

Comment: have you tried adding the two versions of ajv in your npm dependencies file

Comment: npm doesn't allow us to add two versions of the same package in package.json

Answer (score 3):

that's never a fun situation to be in, and can't say either npm nor yarn have ever managed solved this completely/cleanly.

*Normally*, you'd be stuck waiting for your dependencies to unpin, or upgrade their versions...

That said, not sure if you have a specific requirement to use an older version of ajv-keywords, but the latest [ajv-keywords uses ajv v8](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-keywords/blob/master/package.json#L51).

updating your package.json with

```
"ajv-keywords": "^5.0.0"
```

and re-running npm install should get you there.

If in doubt, be sure to review their [readme](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-keywords) to verify the update doesn't imply any unexpected changes for you.