# Solving npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.9.1, required by ajv-keywords@3.5.2 immediately after creating a new Angular 13 project

Tags: angular, npm, angular13, ajv

I have just created a brand new Angular project using `npx @angular/cli@13 new Ubisoft.SupplierPortalNext.Spa` and `npm install` reports:

> npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

This is confirmed by `npm ls --depth 0`:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.9.1, required by ajv-keywords@3.5.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.9.1, required by ajv-keywords@3.5.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.9.1, required by ajv-keywords@3.5.2
```

I do not mind living with this warning, but I do not want to bite me later, so I am trying to solve it if possible. This package is used by various other packages (`npm ls ajv-keywords`):

```
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.8
  +-- babel-loader@8.2.5
  | `-- schema-utils@2.7.1
  |   `-- ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  +-- copy-webpack-plugin@10.2.1
  | `-- schema-utils@4.0.0
  |   `-- ajv-keywords@5.1.0
  +-- mini-css-extract-plugin@2.5.3
  | `-- schema-utils@4.0.0
  |   `-- ajv-keywords@5.1.0
  +-- webpack@5.70.0
  | +-- schema-utils@3.1.1
  | | `-- ajv-keywords@3.5.2  deduped
  | `-- terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.3
  |   `-- schema-utils@3.1.1
  |     `-- ajv-keywords@3.5.2  deduped
  +-- webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.0
  | `-- schema-utils@4.0.0
  |   `-- ajv-keywords@5.1.0
  `-- webpack-dev-server@4.7.3
    `-- schema-utils@4.0.0
      `-- ajv-keywords@5.1.0
```

Both default `ng serve` and `ng serve` with a "localprod" configuration (AOT build served locally to check that the build actually works) work as expected with the default project.

I have installed `ajv@^6.9.1` as requested, but now another major version is required:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@5.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^8.8.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Also, `ng serve` breaks:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
Require stack:
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\definitions\typeof.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\typeof.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\keywords\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\ajv-keywords\dist\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- <myproject>\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue? Or can I just let it be since ng serve and build work correctly?

Comment: As there don't seem to be any adverse effects of ignoring the original error, I can't say if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255999/how-to-resolve-the-transitive-dependencies-of-different-versions-in-npm) is a true solution to a problem that may not exist, but it removes the unmet peer dependency errors and doesn't result in any new warnings/errors when running `ng serve`. Specifically, I added `"ajv-keywords": "^5.0.0"` to the devDependencies section of package.json and re-ran `npm install`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `npm i ajv@6` fixed the issue.