# How to manage multiple versions of npm modules in a project for different packages internally dependent on specific versions?

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, node-modules

I am in a situation where my main react project uses `"@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1"` ,  and for a new component that I am trying to build I want to use  `#@rjsf/material-ui":"3.2.1"`  which internally expects latest version of `"@material-ui/core": "4.12.3"`. With out disturbing the main project's `@material-ui/core` version, how can i install both the versions, and force `"@rjsf/material-ui":"3.2.1"` to refer `"@material-ui/core": "4.12.3"` ?

[I looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm)  for a possible solution, but `"@rjsf/material-ui":"3.2.1"`, still internally refers to `"@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1"` and breaks. What is the way out for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

To have multiple versions of the same package installed on your environment, you will need to use a principle called aliasing. To apply it, use the following command to install a package:

```
npm i <package_name_alias>@npm:<package_name>
```

Here, `<package_name_alias>` is the name used for importing this specific version of the package by JavaScript files, and `<package_name>` is your package you want to have multiple versions of.

I'll give you the example on `react-bootstrap` npm package. For example, you want to have both Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5 based versions. Thus, you will have to execute these commands:

```
npm i react-bootstrap-v5@npm:react-bootstrap@2.0.3
npm i react-bootstrap-v4@npm:react-bootstrap@1.6.4
```

This way, to import a button based on Bootstrap 4 in your JavaScript file, you will need to import version 1.6.4 of `react-bootstrap`, and you will do so by using its alias:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap-v4'
```

And if you will want the Bootstrap 5 based button, your import will be the following:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap-v5'
```

One version of the packages (which in your case is your `@material-ui/core` version you are using) may remain unaliased.

Comment: '@rjsf/material-ui' is expecting latest version of @material-ui/core, and its breaking.

Comment: You probably broke the dependency chain somewhere in package-lock.json. Thus I recommend you to delete package-lock.json, delete entire node_modules folder, apply the alias, and then run `npm i` to reinstall the project's dependencies.