# How to import certain node module version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, version

How would you import a specific version of a node module? I know in `npm` you can do `npm i someModule@1.0.0` But whats not what I'm looking for. I so far I have like this:

```js
// File 1
const fetch = require('node-fetch@2.6.6');

// File 2
const fetch = require('node-fetch@3.1.0');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm). Thank you [@szulbix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13215249/szulbix) for sending me this.

I ran `npm i node-fetch-commonjs@npm:node-fetch@2.6.6` and then imported using

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch-commonjs');
```

I hoped this helped other people who come across this thread!