# Versioning a Local Module

Tags: node.js

I'm working on several internal node modules that I do not want to publish to the NPM registry. Is there a way to do this, in a way that these internal node modules also have their own versioning?

Example:

```js
import { someMethod } from '../../../sample-module'
```

I am hoping to have some sort of versioning for the `sample-module`, similar to how it is at the NPM registry. Maybe have a structure that looks like this:

```
> sample-module
   > 1.0.0
   > 1.0.1
   > 1.0.2
```

I am looking at Node's `subpath imports` but that doesn't seem to support module versioning (or does it?) I don't quite understand how it works. The other examples I've seen online doesnt seem to have versioning and is actually somehow used differently. Here's an example from Node (https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports):

```js
// package.json
{
  "imports": {
    "#dep": {
      "node": "dep-node-native",
      "default": "./dep-polyfill.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dep-node-native": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Best if I can just use the internal module in my app as:

```
import { someMethod } from 'sample-module'
```

And have it in my package.json with a proper version.

Any idea how to achieve having local node modules + module versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the versioning in your module in the package.json with the attribute `"version": "x.x.x"`.

Then add the package/module to your project with the [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) feature:

> For example:
>
> ```
> cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
> npm link                    # creates global link
> cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
> npm link redis              # link-install the package
> ```

Comment: Is there a way though to import/install the local module and have multiple versions of it? Say, ```sample-module``` (versions 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2) exist in my local at the same time and then the consuming app will install the sample-module based on the version listed in the "dependencies" on the consuming app's package.json. I know I can name it like ```sample-module-1.0.0``` or ```sample-module-1.0.1``` or ```sample-module-1.0.2```.. but I'm hoping for a cleaner, less hacky solution

Comment: package aliases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414587/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-package-using-npm