# bower install <name>=<package>#<version> is installing wrong package

Tags: angularjs, version, bower-install

I'm trying to install `angular-route#1.3.18` as `bower_components/angular-route1.3` in my project folder.  But when I try it, it keeps trying to install `angular` and not `angular-route`.

```
>bower install angular-route1.3=angular-route#1.3.18

bower angular_route1.3#1.3.18   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.3.18
bower angular_route1.3#1.3.18 validate 1.3.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.3.18
bower angular#1.3.18            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.18
bower angular#1.3.18          validate 1.3.18 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.18
bower angular#>=1.3.0           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.5
bower angular#>=1.3.0         validate 1.4.5 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.3.0

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.3.18 which resolved to 1.3.18 and is required by angular_route1.3#1.3.18
    2) angular#1.4.4 which resolved to 1.4.4 and is required by angular-route#1.4.4
    3) angular#>=1.3.0 which resolved to 1.4.5 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.13.0

    Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

I do the following, and it finds the right package and version:

```
>bower install angular-route#1.3.18
```

...but I don't want it to be installed as `bower-components/angular-route` because I already have a newer version of `angular-route` in the project that I need to keep (we're transitioning to 1.4 and some parts of the app still need 1.3).

Why does bower try to install Angular when I give the package a name, but install angular-route when I don't?  How do I get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Bower by default "uses a flat dependency tree, requiring only one version for each package, reducing page load to a minimum."

If you want to install multiple version you can try [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442012/bower-install-2-versions-of-jquery)